# Why is my <nav> element ignoring margin rules?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create 10px margin white space around my `<nav class="navlist">`.

I tried adding `margin: 10px;` and `margin-bottom: 10px;` but my `navlist` is glued to my `<div id=header>`.

How can I "push" everything 10px away around my `navlist`, so there is white space between my `class=navlist` and `id=header`?

This is my html and css:

```css
.navlist {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: aqua;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
#header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
.fruitsoorten {
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
#section {
  width: 350px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
#footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navlist">
  <a class="links" href="index.html">Homepage</a>
  <a class="links" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
  <a class="links" href="about.html">about us</a>
</nav>

<div id="header">
  <p>City Gallery</p>
</div>

<div class="fruitsoorten">
  London
  <br>Paris
  <br>Tokyo
</div>

<div id="section">
  <h2>London</h2>
  <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
  <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  Copyright © W3Schools.com
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `nav` has `display: inline`. Switch that to `display: inline-block`.

Top and bottom margins are ignored by `inline` elements.

According to the [CSS Visual Formatting Model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting):

> **9.4.2 Inline formatting contexts**
>
> In an inline formatting context, boxes are laid out horizontally, one
>   after the other, beginning at the top of a containing block.
>   Horizontal margins, borders, and padding are respected between these
>   boxes.

*Horizontal margins* are respected. Vertical margins are not.

In a [block formatting context](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) both horizontal and vertical margins are respected.